# Show the quotient of two numbers of a set remains in that set.

Tags: number-theory

We define a set $S$ as all the integers of the form $x^2+d\cdot y^2$ for some positive integer $d$.

The question is the following:
If $a \in S$ and some prime $p\in S$, such that $p|a$, then is $a/p \in S$?

I proved that for $a,b$ in $S$ then its product is also in $S$. But I don’t know how to start dealing with this problem. Any hint would be appreciated .

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ fixed? Can they be $0$?

Comment: No, S is defined by the numbers that combination defines when $x,y$ moves through $Z$